# ImageView in RelativeView causes crash?

Tags: android, crash, imageview

Whenever I create an ImageView in my XML the emulator crashes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:background="@drawable/words_background">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/letters"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_letters" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moreText"
        android:text="@string/more"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/letters"
        android:layout_below="@id/letters"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/maxSpinner"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/letters"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/letters"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/minSpinner"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/maxSpinner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/letters"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lettersQuestion"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post the exception your are getting from logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the + in a few of your id references, and layout_alignRight will accept "true" or "false" only (you are probably looking for layout_ToRightOf)toTherightOf! AND an ImageView needs height and width set to something.

**You should definitely look at your LogCat for the exact error,**

but your XML should look like this

```
<RelativeLayout id="@+id/rel_layout">
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/maxSpinner"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/letters"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/minSpinner"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maxSpinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/letters"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lettersQuestion" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:text="@string/question" 
        android:gravity="right" 
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```